# Isometry between $C[a,b]$ and $C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, isometry

I need to find isometry between two spaces of continuous functions $C[a,b]$ and $C[0,1]$. That means to find function $ \phi\colon C[a,b] \longrightarrow C[0,1] $ which is bijection and $d_{\infty}(f,g)=d_{\infty}(\phi(f),\phi(g))$. I know that there is bijection between $[a,b]$ and $[0,1]$ $y=(b-a)x +a$. I have idea to every function $g(y) $ from $C[a,b]$ join function $g((b-a)x +a)$ from $C[0,1]$. But I don't know how to prove that this is bijection. I would accept any other way of solving this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply define $\phi(f)(x)=f\bigl((b-a)x+a\bigr)$. Its inverse is $\phi^{-1}(f)(x)=f\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)$. Besides\begin{align}d_\infty\bigl(\phi(f),\phi(g)\bigr)&=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\bigl|f\bigl((b-a)x+1\bigr)-g\bigl((b-a)x+1\bigr)\bigr|\\&=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}\bigl|f(x)-g(x)\bigr|\\&=d_\infty(f,g).\end{align}

Comment: yes,but how to prove that $\phi$  keep distance between functions?

Comment: @John_Stockton I've edited my answer. I hope that it's all clear now.

Comment: Is your$ \phi : C[0,1] \rightarrow C[a,b] $ ?If it is,i think you must prove that  $ d_{\infty}(\phi(f),\phi(g))=d_{\infty}(f,g)$ where $f,g \in C[0,1]$ which means $d_{\infty}(f,g)=sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|$ not $d_{\infty}(f,g)=sup_{x \in [a,b]}|f(x)-g(x)|$

Comment: @John_Stockton No. My map $\phi$ goes in the sense indicated in the title of your question: from $C\bigl([a,b]\bigr)$ into $C\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$.

Answer (score 0):

Define $\psi:[0,1]\to[a,b]$ by $\psi(x)=(b-a)x+a$, and define $\phi:C([a,b])\to C([0,1])$ by $\phi f=f\circ\psi$.  That $\phi$ is a bijection follows from the fact that $\psi$ is a bijection:  Define $\rho:C([0,1])\to C([a,b])$ by $\rho f=f\circ \psi^{-1}$.   Then $\rho\phi f=f\circ(\psi\circ\psi^{-1})=f$ and $\phi\rho f=f\circ(\psi^{-1}\circ\psi)=f$.

That $\phi$ is an isometry can be shown as follows:  since $\phi$ is linear, it suffices to show that $\|\phi f\|=\|f\|$ for all $f\in C([a,b])$.  For such $f$, note that 
$$\{|f(x)|:x\in[a,b]\}=\{|f(\psi(x))|:x\in [0,1]\}=\{|\phi f(x)|:x\in[0,1]\},$$
so taking supremums yields $\|f\|=\|\phi f\|$.